# I have a tap event that I want to overlay over a click event

Tags: jquery

At the moment I'm using `toggleClass` to slide a container to reveal a menu.

```
var btn = $('#headBtn');
var wrap = $('#wrapper');

function slider_click() {
    btn.on('click', function (event) {
        wrap.toggleClass('slideout');
    });
}
slider_click();
```

This works.

I also want to enable tap events on the container to remove the class `.slideout` but when I enable this function the container slides in **but back out again**.

```
function slider_tap() {
    var $ = jQuery;
    var hammertime = Hammer(wrap).on('tap', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('slideout');
    });
```

The button I am using is also part of the container that is listening for the tap events, so when you click the event it seems to trigger the `toggleClass` and the tap event.

How do I enable the tap event and still be able to use my button properly.

I want to be able to slide the container out and be able to tap anywhere on the screen **including the button** to slide it back in again, by removing the class `slideout`.

Comment: can't this be done in jquery alone? what's the hammer thing? Doesn't the click register on a touch device? you can bind click to the document and remove the class

Comment: @Huangism Tap events work faster than click events.

Comment: is this jquery mobile or just jquery?

Comment: @Huangism just jquery, hammer.js is a jquery plugin that registers swipe, drag, tap etc events.

Comment: maybe you can try e.stopPropagation inside of the tap handler assuming it works the same as other jquery handlers. I think what's going on is that when you tap, the tap handler runs and then it propagates to the click handler which is why the menu closes again. The other thing you can try is detecting if the device support touch or not. Bind tap if touch is supported and bind click is touch is not supported

Comment: Yea, I've tried that, there's a link here on using hammer.js event propagation https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Event-delegation-and-how-to-stopPropagation---preventDefaults

Comment: safest way is probably detecting touch support. The code for it you can easily google I think it's quite simple. or just click, it's not that slow

Comment: @Huangism hmm, I guess binding click to the wrapper would do the trick, but that would mean admitting defeat.... I hate admitting defeat. So bind the click to the wrapper and apply `e.stopPropagation` to the wrapper or the button inside the wrapper?

Comment: oh sorry i misread the question. In jquery you can figure out the element that triggered the event, not sure if this is true for hammer. If you can do that then you can say if the trigger element is not the button then remove class

Comment: @Huangism Thanks, I still don't quite know how to incorporate that into my code. Ignoring the hammer code and just sticking with click, could submit an example as an answer for me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick with click will make this work, although slower than tap but it should work

As I was suggesting detecting the event target (where the event originated from) http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

If this works for hammer then you can say something like if the target is the button, don't do anything, else remove class. Assuming the target thing works then

```
var hammertime = Hammer(wrap).on('tap', function (event) {
    if( !$(event.target).is('#headBtn') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('slideout');
    }
});
```